# Flutter expansion tile content is overflowing

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, layout, widget

I am using expansion tile widget in Flutter and the content that i am trying to show does show, but it gives the error of overflow. Here is the code

```
Expanded(
                              child: ExpansionTile(
                                title: customTextWidget(text: "Filter"),
                                leading: const Icon(Icons.filter),
                                children: [
                                  ListView(
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    children: dealController
                                        .filterExpansionCHildrend
                                        .map((e) {
                                      return customTextWidget(text: e.title, );
                                    }).toList(),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
```

Comment: can you include screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Column instead of a ListView or Use **NeverScrollablePhysics()** and **ShrinkWrap** **true**

```
   Expanded(
      child: ExpansionTile(
        title: customTextWidget(text: "Filter"),
        leading: const Icon(Icons.filter),
        children: [
          Column( // Use a Column instead of a ListView
            children: dealController.filterExpansionCHildrend.map((e) {
              return customTextWidget(text: e.title);
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```